# openid question

Tags: openid, janrain

I just started learning about openid and there is something that I am not clear about I was hoping someone could clarify.

I have an exsiting user table say

userid | email | password | firstname | lastname

and another table that stores scores

userid | score

If I implement an openid solution like Janrain engage from
http://www.janrain.com/products/engage

after the person logs in with an open id, I want to store that user in my DB so that I can keep track of his score...

Is this the idea of the janrain openid?...that once the person logs in from another provider, I have to then use some of the info to populate my own user table just "without the password"...Then next time when he signs in using the same openid, I can then pull the score from my score table.

let me know if I am not making it clear and I will update =)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you look at some of the existing implementations to understand how to build your app.

The [django-janrain](https://github.com/citadelgrad/django-janrain) project is a simple implement in python and it uses the built-in django User app so it is pretty straight forward. This is my fork which has two minor modifications.

Janrain provides [sample code](https://github.com/janrain/Janrain-Sample-Code) that has good explanations but are not complete implementations.